# Make a left float expand to match two rightfloated siblings

Tags: html, css

I have a container with 3 boxes. Two boxes float to the right and take up about 50% in height of the parent div(ofter overflow-y: hidden on the parent div), so they are the same size. They have a sibling that floats to the left which I want to expand in height based on its 2 siblings height(thus the parent height).

I do not want to set the parent to a fixed height if I can avoid it(since well it can change size if the browser size changes).

A [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vq5c/1/)

```
  <article>
    <div class="box-container">
        <section class="box-half left-box">
            <h3>Bigger box</h3>

            <div class="chart">
                <p>I want this box to fill the entire height</p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="box-half">
            <div>
                <h3>One half box</h3><span>With some text</span>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="box-half">
            <div>
                <h3>Another half box</h3><span>With another text</span>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</article>




 *, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left-box {
    background: white !important; 
}

.box-container {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

article {
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
}

.box-full,
.box-half {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0.25em;
    text-align: center;
}

.box-half {
    width: 50%;
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `display:table` and `display:table-cell` instead of `float`... see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vq5c/4/)

Comment: and if I want the .chart to be able to expand the full height of the table-cell (#left) except of cause the <h3>biggerbox</h3> .

Comment: what do you mean? you want it to be centered vertically?

Comment: This fiddle shows it: http://jsfiddle.net/8vq5c/5/
the table which is inside it all should also expand in height. Without setting .chart to the fixed height.